# how to do Json format

Tags: python, nltk, entity-relationship, named-entity-recognition

```
 (S
  (PERSON Rami/NNP Eid/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  studying/VBG
  at/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Stony/NNP Brook/NNP University/NNP)
  in/IN
  (LOCATION NY/NNP))
```

This is output of NLTK code now i want to store it in json file like

```
import json

data = {
        'Rami Eid':{'ORGANIZATION': 'Stony Brook University',  'location':'NY'},
        'GuruRaj Bagali':{'job': 'professor', 'location': 'NY'}
       }
```

I want store chunk tree into json file like above format how to do?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the `NLTK` output and turn it into that dictionary?

Comment: How to do tree structure of data into json format like above

Comment: Use the NLTK API to find the specific elements in the parse tree that you want, and then add them to the dictionary.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178585/how-to-do-json-format-using-nltk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173045/how-to-store-ner-result-in-json-database

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Yes, this is easy if you have the data already in a dict. The OP doesn't have the data dict, just the nested NLTK output, and wants to create the dict.

Comment: I think the question is how to turn the ntlk into json, not how to write a dictionary to a file

Comment: How to do tree structure of data into json format like above. I want how to represent json structure

Comment: They want data to be saved in a `.json` file, not a `.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
nltk = """
(S
  (PERSON Rami/NNP Eid/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  studying/VBG
  at/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Stony/NNP Brook/NNP University/NNP)
  in/IN
  (LOCATION NY/NNP)) """

from pyparsing import Suppress, ungroup, Word, alphas, Group, Dict, OneOrMore

LPAR,RPAR,SLASH = map(Suppress,"()/")

parsed_word = ungroup(Word(alphas) + Suppress(SLASH + Word(alphas)))
named_token = Group(LPAR + Word(alphas)("name") + 
                    OneOrMore(parsed_word).setParseAction(' '.join)("value") + 
                    RPAR)

subject = (Suppress("S") + named_token)

nltk_expr = (LPAR + subject("subject") + 
             Dict(OneOrMore(named_token | Suppress(parsed_word)))("predicate") + 
             RPAR)

def make_subject_main_key(t):
    subname = t.pop('subject')[0].value
    subdesc = t.pop('predicate')
    t[subname] = subdesc
nltk_expr.setParseAction(make_subject_main_key)

print nltk_expr.parseString(nltk).asDict()
```

prints

```
{'Rami Eid': {'ORGANIZATION': 'Stony Brook University', 'LOCATION': 'NY'}}
```

Comment: But out put of above code is                                                               {'Rami Eid': ([(['ORGANIZATION', 'Stony Brook University'], {'name': [('ORGANIZATION', 0)], 'value': [('Stony Brook University', 1)]}), (['LOCATION', 'NY'], {'name': [('LOCATION', 0)], 'value': [('NY', 1)]})], {'ORGANIZATION': [('Stony Brook University', 0)], 'LOCATION': [('NY', 1)]})}

Comment: its not like {'Rami Eid': {'ORGANIZATION': 'Stony Brook University', 'LOCATION': 'NY'}}

Comment: My bad, I'm using a version of pyparsing that I hasn't been released yet.

Comment: You can get the version of pyparsing that gives this result from the SourceForge SVN repository: http://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/  Just extract `pyparsing.py` and save it to your local source directory.  Then when I get the version released, you can upgrade pyparsing and then just delete your local copy.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you nicely formatted json file.

```
 with open('/path/to/your/new_json_file.json', "w") as f:
     f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This will create a file `your_json_file.json` in in `your/` directory with.

```
{
    "GuruRaj Bagali": {
        "job": "professor",
        "location": "NY"
    },
    "Rami Eid": {
        "ORGANIZATION": "Stony Brook University",
        "location": "NY"
    }
}
```

The indentation and sort_keys arguments are optional.  Depending on how you're using it they may be nice to have.

You could also put the same data on one line and wouldn't need to import json.

```
 with open('/path/to/your/new_json_file.json', "w") as f:
     f.write('%s' % data)
```

Will create
`{'Rami Eid': {'ORGANIZATION': 'Stony Brook University', 'location': 'NY'}, 'GuruRaj Bagali': {'job': 'professor', 'location': 'NY'}}`